# Fetch a particular String in <div> using xpath

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, dom, xpath, assert

I have the following DOM structure / HTML:

```
<div class = "something" >
    <div>
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
"Automated Script"
</div>
```

I am testing using Selenium Webdriver and have to fetch the string Automated Script to do an Assert.

```
Assert.assertEquals("Automated Script",webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/div")).getText());
```

But the above xpath fetches both Some Text and Automated Script.
Is there a way to only get the string Automated Script?

Comment: Originally the expected value in the Assert is a String Variable so I have fetch the string as in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `assertEquals`:

```
String divText = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.something")).getText();
String spanText = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.something span")).getText();
String expectedText = divText.replace(spanText, "").strip();
Assert.assertEquals("Automated Script", expectedText);
```

With contains and `asserTrue`:

```
Assert.assertTrue(webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.something")).getText().contains("Automated Script"));
```

Using `WebDriverWait`, that will wait for text and through an error:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.something"), "Automated Script"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is work around to execute `text()` in xpath in selenium. Directly it won't work in selenium

Use `evaluate()` method of JavaScript and evaluate your xpath using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object message = js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='something']/text()\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println(message.toString().trim());
```